# Cannot get a hold on my Preferences with Unified Preferences

Tags: android, android-preferences

I use [this](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference) library to create my `PreferenceActivity`. It works quite fine so far but I can not set any listeners on my Preference.

That how my `Activity` looks like:

```
public class PrefActivity extends UnifiedSherlockPreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHeaderRes(R.xml.preference_headers);
        // Set desired preference file and mode (optional)
        setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Preference p = (Preference)findPreference("deleteSavedSearches");
        p.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) { 
                            //code for what you want it to do   
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
    }
}
```

This is my PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <Preference
        android:key="deleteSavedSearches"
        android:summary="Gespeicherte Suchen löschen"
        android:title="Gespeicherte Suchen löschen" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And those are my headers:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:unified="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <!--
    /*
    ** Header definitions are identical to android:* except for preferenceRes which should be a reference to a preference xml file
    ** Unlike the native headers these are also used for building the single pane version.
    */
    -->
    <header
        unified:fragment="com.example.skelett.PrefActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
        unified:preferenceRes="@xml/pref_country"
        unified:title="Land" />
    <header
        unified:fragment="com.example.skelett.PrefActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
        unified:preferenceRes="@xml/pref_data"
        unified:title="Daten" />

</preference-headers>
```

In this case, `p` is `null`. `getPreferenceScreen()` also always returns `null`. I have my keys set up in the preference xml. What am I missing?

Comment: where u are setting SharedPreferences name to `deleteSavedSearches` ?

Comment: Edited, as you can see the key is set.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the findPreference method in onPostCreate and should work:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Preference p = (Preference) findPreference("deleteSavedSearches");
    p.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
            // code for what you want it to do
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```